# Is there an accepted pythonic way of splitting off a base class part from a subclass object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for the best way to split off the base class content of a subclass object. That is, if I have an object `b` of class `B`, which subclasses class `A`, I would like a method for class `B` that returns an object `a` of class `A` with the relevant content taken from `b` (which is a subset of all the content in `b`). Currently I have roughly the following (the actual classes are more complicated of course, this is a simplified toy example)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def update(self, dx):
        self.x += dx

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.y = None

    def update(self, dx):
        super().update(dx)
        self.y = self.x*self.x

    def split_off_base_part(self):
        a = A()
        a.__dict__.update({k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if k in a.__dict__})
        return a
```

but I am not too happy with it. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this? Possibly one that doesn't require calling `A.__init__` or is this simply not possible in general?

Comment: The idea that an object consists of discrete parts that come from one class or another doesn't exist in Python. An object just *is*: its attributes are agnostic as to which class may have initialized them, and inheritance is only an issue during method lookup.

Comment: Instance state isn't really tied to any particular class, even though you the developer may know that it happens to be set in a super-class initializer, the *object* sure doesn't know that, unlike the class state, which would be instrospectable. Indeed, instance state can be set *anywhere*. If you really need to do something like this (I would like to hear the use case... maybe this could all be avoided with a different design) then you should write your classes to support this, perhaps by requriing explicit enumeration of the instance attributes. Maybe use `__slots__`?

Comment: You might also consider that `B` doesn't *inherit* from `A`, but rather each instance of `B`  creates or has a reference to an instance of `A`.

Comment: @chepner yes if this indeed exists I would like to exactly access or return that instance of `A` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could re-define the `init` for `A` so that it can optionally take parameters, that is nice than trying to `update` the `__dict__`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, _x = 0):
        self.x = _x

    def update(self, dx):
        self.x += dx

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.y = None

    def update(self, dx):
        super().update(dx)
        self.y = self.x*self.x

    def toA(self):
        return A(self.x)
```

---

Or you could define that as a class-method (almost like a second constructor) on `A`, which takes a `B` and returns a stripped down `A`.